# Liferay: Json parse object in a hook

Tags: java, json, liferay, hook

I'm developing a hook. I would to parse a json String. So I thought about json-simple API. I added the corresponding jar to the buildPath. 
When I deployed the hook I got the following error message:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject; 
    [javac]            
    [javac] The import org.json cannot be resolved
```

What I understood after I made a search in the net is that we can't add a jar lib to a hook in the buildPath.

So is there an other solution to parse a Json String in Liferay? Is there a specific json API for Liferay?

Answer (score 0):

You totally can add libraries to hooks. They're web applications like others. Just make sure to not only add them to build dependencies, but also deploy them in WEB-INF/lib.

Additionally, you might want to make sure that the libraries you add don't conflict with other versions of the same lib that might be deployed. But I don't see a problem in this case.

Also, you mention that your problem is "when you deploy" the hook, but list a javac message - this sounds rather like build time than deployment time. Check your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is a deploy problem? Because I read javac error messages.

By the way this is a general response for people with the same question:

As you can see visiting official Liferay Javadoc, there are JSON APIs available for you.

Following is a URL from the 6.2 API, but it is available for 6.1 and 6.0 also (I don't remember if previous LR versions provide this API): https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/json/JSONObject.html

Just a suggestion: before including external third part libraries, make sure that LR doesn't provide them yet... this is to avoid conflicts and classpath problems.